# using like statement with Specified and Wildcard for numbers

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

Using SQL Server,

I am currently trying the retrieve data with the Beginning  letters of a postcode followed by a Wildcard for the rest of the characters.

For example in the below I want to find all the postcodes for Birmingham using the letter B. However this also find other entries such postcode with BB which is for blackburn.

Can you advise me how I can use the beginning letters of a postcode to find all the correct entries containing it?

```
Select * from SCSite where Site_Post_Code like 'B%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on the database.  In SQL Server, you can put character ranges in the `like` pattern:

```
select *
from SCSite
where Site_Post_Code like 'B[0-9]%'
```

Other databases are more likely to do this with a regular expression.  Here is an example:

```
select *
from SCSite
where Site_Post_Code regexp '^B[0-9]'
```

Comment: Hi , sorry Yes it was for SQL server. That has done the trick. Thank you for your prompt reply.